# How to split and concat video using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having issues running this command. I am trying to split, concat and create an .mp4 output but keep getting this error:

`Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v]trim=1:130.5421184320267,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0.1]; [0:a:0]atrim=1:130.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0.1]; [0:a:1]atrim=1:130.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0.2]; [v0.1][a0.1] [a0.2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=2[out_1] matches no streams.`

The command itself is:

```
ffmpeg -y -f mxf -i 158907_019_1790823_1.mxf -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif,split=2[out1][out2]" -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif,split=2[out1][out2]" -map "[out1]" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=1:130.5421184320267,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0.1]; [0:a:0]atrim=1:130.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0.1]; \
[0:a:1]atrim=1:130.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0.2]; [v0.1][a0.1] [a0.2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=2[out_1]" -map "[out_1]" -r 29.97 output_1.mp4 -map "[out2]" -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=1:190.5421184320267,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0.1]; \
[0:a:0]atrim=130:190.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0.1]; \
[0:a:1]atrim=130:190.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0.2]; [v0.1][a0.1]\
[a0.2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=2[out_2]" -map "[out_2]" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 output_2.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your input may not contain two audio streams

Without the complete log from your command I can only speculate, but I assume this is the reason for "`Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description...matches no streams`".

## Do all filtering in one filtergraph

Otherwise the input/output labeling gets messy, mistakes or errors are more likely, and whole filtergraphs may get ignored.

## MP4 does not support ProRes

Output to `.mov` instead of `.mp4`.

---

#### Example

```
ffmpeg -y -i 158907_019_1790823_1.mxf -filter_complex \
"[0:v]yadif,fps=ntsc,split=2[y1][y2]; \
 [y1]trim=1:130.5421184320267,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [y2]trim=1:190.5421184320267,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [0:a:0]atrim=1:130.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1]; \
 [0:a:1]atrim=1:130.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2]; \
 [0:a:0]atrim=130:190.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b1]; \
 [0:a:1]atrim=130:190.5421184320267,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b2]; \
 [v1][a1][a2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=2[out_v1][out_a1][out_a2]; \
 [v2][b1][b2]concat=n=1:v=1:a=2[out_v2][out_b1][out_b2]" \
-map "[out_v1]" -map "[out_a1]" -map "[out_a2]" output_1.mp4 \
-map "[out_v2]" -map "[out_b1]" -map "[out_b2]" -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 output_2.mov
```